# using explode with foreach, str_word_count returns zero

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    $urls= file_get_contents("./url.txt");
    $arrays = explode("\n", $urls);
    function get_data($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 5;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
      }
/* gets the data from a URL */

    foreach ($arrays as $link) {

      echo '<a href="http://' . $link .'">' . $link . '</a><br />' . " \n";
      $returned_content = get_data('$link');
      print_r(str_word_count($returned_content));
      echo '<br />';
      }

    ?>
```

What I am trying to do is to explode a file with multiple urls each separated by linebreaks, open each link with curl & get the word count for the page. In the end I require the link & the word count below it. I am currently getting a 0 for word count. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly - does get data really need an `<a>` tag? Or just the URL? Secondly, you're passing it `'$link'`, which is a string literal, containing `$link` - you don't need the quotes there.

Answer (score 1):

on the line `$returned_content = get_data('$link');`

it should be `$returned_content = get_data($link);` instead...

what the first one is doing is passing a string "$link" and not the value inside the $link variable..

Answer (score 0):

The param provided to get_data() method is incorrect. it should rather be, `get_data($link)` instead of `get_data('$link');`